# Javascript loses communication with flash when moved inside dom

Tags: javascript, flash

Code inside Actionscript:

```
var methodName4:String = "startupload";
var instance4:Object = null;
var method4:Function = startupload;
var wasSuccessful4:Boolean = ExternalInterface.addCallback(methodName4, instance4, method4);
function startupload(currently_uploading_id) {

    /* If there is still more photos to upload, then proceed to next one */
    if((max_photo_number - session_photos))
    {
        uploadthis(selected_photos,currently_uploading_id);
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="e_upload" class="hidden">
    <div id="upload_container">
```

```
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:
when dom is loaded:

```
var cached_flash = $('#e_upload').html();
$('#e_upload').html('');

When generating html via javascript:
$(cached_flash).appendTo(full_ad.find('#e_upload_wrapper')).show();
```

That's it. When i'm trying to upload somethin, startupload function inside flash is not working anymore.

Calling Actionscript this way:

```
/* Sending back to Flash */
function thisMovie(movieName) {

    if (window.document[movieName]) {
        return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
    }

}

thisMovie('fileref').startupload(currently_uploading_array_slot);
```

Actionscript is calling javascript functions from inside just fine, but javascript is not.

What is the problem? How to rebind startupload function?

Comment: When i'm positioning absolute and just move needed place, it's all working.

But when i copy html and put into new place, binded functions doesn't work anymore. How to rebind them at new place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you accessing document body, but your swf is deeper, so access it directly:

so not `document.getElementById(movieName)` but `document.getElementById(e_upload).getElementById(movieName)`

Comment: Interesting, i'll try it. But i don't think the problem is in this. I'll check and post here if it will help.

Comment: It's some kind of bug inside plugin_container.exe or inside Firefox or even maybe because i'm using old flash and compile into 8.0. Whatever it was, i have positioned flash absolutely on the page without moving it inside dom. that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same problem with this.

[Can I move a Flash object within the DOM without it reloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963283/can-i-move-a-flash-object-within-the-dom-without-it-reloading)

When you move flash it's CSS box is destroyed and recreated. For various reasons (refer to the link for more) the plugin state is stored in the CSS box and not in the DOM object and therefore the plugin is "reset". That means that the object variable you use to communicate with the plugin no longer hold a valid reference since the plugin has been reloaded.