# Moving a Flash object within the DOM tree

Tags: html, flash

I have found this question; [Can I move a Flash object within the DOM without it reloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963283/can-i-move-a-flash-object-within-the-dom-without-it-reloading)

I m developing a simple video chat application. Whenever I move a flash object within the dom tree, it resets itself. I know there is no solution for it which is a browser specific behaviour. However, I would like to ask whether there is any workaround to do this. My requirements are simple. I have multiple streams which are aligned horizontally. Every stream is a different flash object. When someone enlarges a single Flash object, I need to move it to the top. Whenever I move it to the top, that particular video resets itself, and you wait for a couple of second to get the stream back. Is there any workaround or any way to avoid this.

I am currently simply prepending the same list item to the same parent. This is a very important feature and any kind of solution which doesn't require flash to reset itself is acceptable. (Except creating a parent flash container which has all the streams within it.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that a div with absolute position, and changing x/y coordinates worked for me (I haven't done any extensive testing though). Could give it a try.

Comment: Yeah that can work! How couldn't I think that? I'll test it cross-browser and post the result after the easter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem some time ago. I found it cannot be done. If you move the element containing your flash in the dom tree, it reloades. I solved this by setting the position of the container element to absolute and changing it position on the stage by changeing its x and y