# Flex app as tab in a html 5 application

Tags: angularjs, apache-flex, swfobject

I need to have a flex application as one of the tabs in html 5 application.
But the problem is when i move across different tabs (one being the html and other being flash ) inside the html application the flash reloads.

The question: Is there a way , we can stop flash from reloading and can maintain the state inside the flash.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you switch tabs, your swf is removed / added to the DOM which causes the swf to reload.
You have to find a way to make the swf invisible but remain in the DOM when you switch tabs. 
Make sure you do not move it inside the dom, (take it out and insert is somewhere else) that will also trigger a reload.

I had a similar problem once and managed to solve it: [Moving a Flash object within the DOM tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031129/moving-a-flash-object-within-the-dom-tree/10031422#10031422)

(At least I think this is your problem since you haven't provided any code :-) )